# Numeric IP address of a website

Tags: ip, ip-address, web-hosting, host

I am trying to get the IP address which loads a certain website. For example; `www.smmadmin.com` - I tried `http://192.185.77.222/` but that shows 404 page, the IP address is given by getip.com

How does this thing work? and how to get the actual IP address?

Answer (score 0):

You can simply try ping command if you are on Windows.

ping www.smmadmin.com

Let me know if it doesn't work

Comment: No, that doesn't open up the homepage, you could try that yourself

Comment: May be the server your site is using [http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/vhosts/name-based.html](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/vhosts/name-based.html). I too have a website named www.harshavmb.com and I'm unable to access my website using ip address. This is most common technique used for cheap hosting. So to bundle together, in Name Based Virtual Hosts, same ip is shared by many hosts.